# Display title of current page in ionic side menu header

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following code for a side menu in the body of my **index.html** which works. But I can't figure out how to change the `Page Title` to display the title of the current page.

```
<ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-view class="has-header"></ion-nav-view>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="button icon button-clear ion-navicon-round"
                        ng-click="toggleLeft()"></button>
            </div>
            <h1 class="title">Page Title</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item href="#/dash">Dashboard</ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item href="#/search">Search</ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

NOTE: Use Shrinath's answer and place your content in a `<ion-content>` tag after the `ion-header-bar` tag to stop the content being stacked under the header.

Comment: you can bind Page title from the controller on every page

Comment: I tried adding {{title}} to the HTML and $scope.title="Current Page Header" to the controllers for dash and search. But that doesn't display. Although if I add the same thing to my MainCtrl for the index.html page it does work. So it seems that the menu isn't accessible from the scope of the individual controllers for each page.

Comment: do `$rootScope.title` rather than `$scope.title`

Comment: Can you add whole code here. or create plunker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use route and for every route define template having different controller.
On Template definition you can choose different Header.

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
        <h1 class="title">Heading</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
```

Comment: Thanks, I deleted my answer, as it quickly stopped working. Your method works well.